# In c++ what does Ptr<> a stands for?

Tags: c++, pointers, operators

Im actually analysing some cod and i found this

```
 Ptr<UniformRandomVariable> m_yMinVar;
```

i have some c experience but no c++, what i understand is that the line declare a pointer call m_yMinVar and it's "type" `<UniformRandomVariable>` where "UniformRandomVariable" must be a class in other cpp file but i really dnot know,

i would like to know exactly what's Ptr because my text editor reconizes it as a variable type

also "<>" i'm not sure thats that

and finaly if someone can share me a link where i can see operators and diferent kinds of declaring variables and coding types like " i++ = i+=  i=i+1"

doodbye everybody and thank u all

Comment: `Ptr` is the name of a template that has been defined prior to its use.

Comment: You have two different and unrelated questions, please post it as two different and separate questions. But note that the second will be voted as off-topic. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: It also seems like you could use [a good book or two to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Answer (score 2):

`Ptr<UniformRandomVariable>` is an instantiation of a class template. Instances of class templates are classes. Classes are user defined types. `Ptr<UniformRandomVariable> m_yMinVar;` as a whole is declaration of a variable of type `Ptr<UniformRandomVariable>`.

`Ptr` is the name of the template. Given the name, it would be fairly safe to assume that it is some sort of a wrapper around a pointer. If the first template argument of `Ptr` is a type argument, then `UniformRandomVariable` is the name of some type. It may be a class, or a typedef. If the first template argument of `Ptr` is a non-type argument, then `UniformRandomVariable` is some constant value.

`Ptr` must be defined within the same translation unit (prior to the instantiation). `UniformRandomVariable` must be at least declared in the same translation unit where it is used in the instantiation, and depending on the definition of the `Ptr` template, `UniformRandomVariable` may also need to be defined.